# How can overcome ng bootstrap Carousel component has white space in right side

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have tried ng bootstrap Carousel for my application. But when I used this there is white space right hand side for page:

I have mentioned below tried code:

bags.component.html

```
<ngb-carousel *ngIf="images">
    <ng-template ngbSlide>
      <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
        <img [src]="images[0]" alt="Random first slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>First slide label</h3>
        <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbSlide>
      <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
        <img [src]="images[1]" alt="Random second slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Second slide label</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbSlide>
      <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
        <img [src]="images[2]" alt="Random third slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Third slide label</h3>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-carousel>
```

bags.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bags',
  templateUrl: './bags.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bags.component.css']
})
export class BagsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  images = [944, 1011, 984].map((n) => `https://picsum.photos/id/${n}/900/500`);
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Tried solution:

```
.row.carousel-inner {
    margin: 0;
}

.row {
    margin: 0!important;
}
```

My tried solution also not worked. How can I solve this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there an error in .css

```
ngb-carousel .picsum-img-wrapper>img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width:100%; //<--use width 100%, not left:0
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: When I use `ngb-carousel .picsum-img-wrapper>img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width:100%;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
  }`
 in my bags.component.css, nothing display

Comment: check where you has defined your picsum-img-wrapper class, is there where you need change the line. In the example of the page:https://stackblitz.com/run?file=app/carousel-basic.ts is defined directly in the .html, you should has in component, in this forked stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mbsks4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcarousel-basic.ts I put it using `styles` but you can use also stylesurl